# Using nested query in AWS log insights

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudwatch, amazon-cloudwatchlogs, aws-cloudwatch-log-insights

I am using AWS Lambdas to host some services. To mitigate issue of cold start, I'm using [serverless plugin warmup](https://www.serverless.com/plugins/serverless-plugin-warmup).

Now using cloudwatch log insights, I intend to figure out p99/p95 of all the requests going to my lambda but exclude requests made by the plugin. For this one query which should help is , figure out requestIDs for plugin calls ( I'm logging a certain message based on which I can filter out those requests ). Now I want all those requests whose request IDS are not in these requests IDs. In sql this would transform to a nested query.

Rough version :

`SELECT @duration from requestIDs where requestID not in ( SELECT RequestID where @message like ***** )`

Do we have a way in which I can do such query in Log Insights?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can remove messages from the warmup plugin by piping all messages to the filter with `not like` condition and then to `pct(fieldName: LogFieldValue, percent: number)` function:

```
fields @duration
| filter @message not like "MESSAGE TO EXCLUDE"
| stats pct(@duration, 99)
```

Comment: Yeah that I get. But the time durations like @initDuration is part of another message and not part of console.log message.

Comment: Got it, let me know if the corrected version of the answer solves your problem.

Comment: Hi, actually no it will not work. For a single request my log trail looks like :

`START requestID1 xxxx`

`INFO requestID1 CustomMessage`

`END requestID1 xxxxx`

`REPORT requestID1 xxxxx`

And then another log trail let's say : 



`START requestID2 xxxx`

`INFO requestID2 randomMessage`

`END requestID2 xxxxx`

`REPORT requestID2 xxxxx`



Your answer will still give me durations from reports of `requestID1` which have this CustomMessage in @message.

Comment: Why is this message random?